# UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the KosmosFileSystem FileSystem implementation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'd like to know your input as to why this error is happening. On production environment onshore, we're using CDH4. On our local testing environment, we're just using Apache Hadoop v2.2.0. When I run the same jar compiled on CDH4, the MR jobs are executed fine. But when I run the jar on Hadoop v2.2.0 (YARN enabled), I get this error:

`INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1391062333435_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the KosmosFileSystem FileSystem implementation`

The log showed Map jobs ran successfully, but the Reduce jobs - all of them failed - with the above error. There's not too many hits on Google regarding this error so I'm kind of nowhere to run but here.

Any thoughts guys? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, production environment (CDH4) is not using YARN

Comment: I am getting the same error but at the very beginning, namely at setInputPaths. Any solution yet?

Comment: I am getting the same error when i run on CDH5. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lateness of this reply. 
This problem was solved when we synched our environment with the one onshore. That is, instead of using plain Apache Hadoop, we used the Cloudera distribution.